# Fastest way to find a 3X3 square of intigers in a string

Tags: performance, python-2.7, matrix, lookup

I have a string with the length of 480000 , it represents a 800x600 frame.
meaning 600 rows and 800 columns. i need to find a square of 3X3 were all the 9 values are in a specific range. i have the range itself. and return the index of the middle.

this is what i am doing right now:

```
    # find 3x3  minValue < square < maxVlaue
    for row in range(598):
        for col in range(798):
            if checkRow(frame,row,col,minValue,maxValue): 
                if checkRow(frame,row+1,col,minValue,maxValue):
                    if checkRow(frame,row+2,col,minValue,maxValue):
                    string = str(row+1),str(col+1)
                    print string
                    return 


def checkRow(Frame,row,col,minValue,maxValue):
    if (Frame[row*800+col])>minValue) and (Frame[row*800+col])<maxValue):
        if (Frame[row*800+col+1])>minValue) and (Frame[row*800+col+1])<maxValue):
            if (Frame[row*800+col+2])>minValue) and (Frame[row*800+col+2])<maxValue):
                return True 
    return False
```

this way i check each "pixel" until the square is found.

is there some kind of special function in python for this job?
or maybe a faster and more efficient algorithm?

i thought about checking a pixel every 2 columns and skipping 2 rows. this way i can make sure i wont miss the 3x3 square, but this way when i hit a pixel , i need to check 9 different options for the square itself. so i am not sure how much faster it will be.

thanks

Comment: In Python, `Frame[row*800+col])>minValue) and (Frame[row*800+col])<maxValue` can be written `minValue<Frame[row*800+col]<maxValue`.  I assume this means that everything in `Frame` is an integer, but you're only interested in the ones in the specific range.  Is everything in `Frame` a digit in 0-9?  You could do an initial filtering with the regular expression `\d{3}`.

Comment: The values are from 0 to 255. What does this expression mean?

Comment: You said you "have a string with the length of 480000", which I thought might be like "...123abc456def789...".  If that had been the case, you'd be interested in the regular expression `\d{3}`, which means: "three digits from 0-9".  But it's sounding like `Frame` is actually a tuple.  You may want to work with `Frame[row*800+col:row*800+col+3]`, which extracts three elements at once (see ["slice"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range)).  I think your eventual answer will depend on how big your range is.  Are most entries within the range?  Or outside?

Comment: at least 20% of the values are in the range.